# Add properties of unknown name to expando object

Tags: c#

I wanna do something like this:

```
 dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    if (line.Contains(":"))
    {
        var data = line.Split(':');
        if (data.Length >= 2)
        {
            eo.data[0] = data[1];
        }
    }
```

That is : add a property which name is located inside this array.
I get :  `'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'data'`

I want to create this property at run time : the name of the property must be the same as the name of the value which is inside the data array at position 0

Comment: So define a `data` field?

Comment: you should first define what `data` is before using an indexer on it.

Comment: I know what data is, data[0] is a string I want to name the property the same as the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but:

Assuming `data[0]` contains the string `"hello"` and `data[1]` contains the string `"world"`, I believe what you're trying to do is this (pseudocode):

```
eo.hello = world;
```

If so, you can simply cast the [`ExpandoObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055717/add-properties-of-unknown-name-to-expando-object/30055802#30055717) to `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
var dictionary = eo as IDictionary<string, object>;
dictionary.Add(data[0], data[1]);
```